# How to access the asset in workflow process step

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, aem, sling

I am trying to write a workflow `process step` for the `DAM update asset` such that the uploaded asset will be sent to an external service that will modify the asset and then the modified asset can be sent to the `Metadata extraction` step. So I've added my process step to the DAM update asset like this:

[image]

And my code looks like this so far:

```
public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession wfsession,MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
    try
    {
        log.info("Here2 in execute method");    //ensure that the execute method is invoked

        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put( "user.jcr.session", wfsession.getSession());

        ResourceResolver rr = resolverFactory.getResourceResolver(map);
        String path = item.getWorkflowData().getPayload().toString();
        log.info("Here2 path: " + path);
        Resource resource = rr.getResource(path);
        log.info("Here2 resource: " + resource);
        InputStream is = resource.adaptTo(InputStream.class);
        log.info("Here2 assets IS: " + is);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.info("Here Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what I see in the logs when I upload an asset:

Here2 in execute method
Here2 path: /content/dam/photo1.JPG/jcr:content/renditions/original
Here2 asset: null

**Question**

- My external service has an API accepting requests over HTTP. How should I send over the asset to the external service?
- Once the external service modifies the asset, what should I do so that the Metadata extraction step reads the modified asset instead of the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access your external service via HTTP, you have to write a client. CQ provides [`commons-httpclient`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1) bundle and you may use it to access the service. Documentation for the library can be found [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). I don't know if the service expects that the file will be send using PUT or POST, but httpclient provides all these methods. All you have to do is to provide appropriate `InputStream`. Adapt your resource to [`Rendition`](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/Rendition.html) and use `getStream()` method to get the `InputStream`.

When you'll get the modified asset from the webservice, you need to replace the original one:

```
// rendition = ...;      // original rendition object created as above
// newInputStream = ...; // new asset received from your webservice
Asset asset = rendition.getAsset();
asset.addRendition("original", newInputStream, rendition.getMimeType());
```