# Uploading multiple assets to the DAM messes the workflow process step

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473136/how-to-access-the-asset-in-workflow-process-step) about how to access the uploaded asset, send it to a third party service, and then replace the asset with the one sent back from the third party service.

I got a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24474096/654203) for that question, using which I was able to write the code below which works well when I upload single assets, however, it **does not** work when I upload multiple assets at the same time. When I upload multiple assets at the same time, the assets names and content are not what is uploaded. For example if I upload `1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg` then randomly it will replace contents of `1.jpg` with `2.jpg` or `4.jpg` content with `3.jpg` etc.

```
    public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession wfsession,MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
        try
        {
            final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put( "user.jcr.session", wfsession.getSession());

            ResourceResolver rr = resolverFactory.getResourceResolver(map);
            String path = item.getWorkflowData().getPayload().toString();
            Resource resource = rr.getResource(path);
            InputStream is = resource.adaptTo(InputStream.class);
            Rendition rendition = resource.adaptTo(Rendition.class);
            Asset asset = rendition.getAsset();
            //send the asset to service and get newInputStream from the service
            InputStream newInputStream = myService.sendFile(is);
            //replace the original rendition with the one received from the service
            asset.addRendition(rendition.getName(),newInputStream,asset.getMimeType());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {...}
   }
```

**Question**

- I'm wondering if there is a way I can change my code to handle the use case of uploading multiple assets at the same time. I believe this is happening because of the response from my service to return the inputstream might not be finished before CQ5 sends a new asset. Is there a way to block off this so that my process step works on one image at a time?

Note:

- I have `Handler Advance` option checked for my `Process Step`
- From my testing: everything is ok if I upload two assets at the same time...anything more than that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading an asset creates a new workflow instance (you may see those in the workflow console), with a separate `WorkflowData`, payload, etc. Therefore, the out-of-the-box workflow *Update Asset* works fine even for many assets uploaded simultaneously.

If you have problems with such case, please review your custom process and the `myService` to see if it's thread safe. Remember that OSGi creates just one instance of the `@Component`, so such components shouldn't have a state dependent on the current request, current workflow and - in general - current thread.

As a rule-of-thumb: classes being OSGi components should declare only fields containing objects that can be shared amongst many threads, like `@Reference`s to other services and configuration properties.